# Can we use Compiz or KWin on Mir?

Tags: compiz, mir

I like to customize my desktop , so is there any compiz replacement for mir ?

EDIT : 
I mean , can we customize (Unity Next) and use compiz on it ?

Answer (score 2):

Compiz is a compositing engine. It was designed to add compositing capabilities to window managers that run on top of X.

Mir has a compositing engine built in.

The two would be contradictory, so you cannot use Compiz on top of Mir.